# SQL Update with where clause has group by and having statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update the export column on all rows that match my WHERE clause criteria and it is Updating all rows instead

Here is what I have so far

```
 Create table Temp (
  Employeeid nvarchar(10),
  Punchtype nvarchar (2),
  Date Date,
  TotalTime decimal (16,2),
  Job nvarchar(10),
  Exported bit not null Default 0)

  Insert Into Temp (Employeeid,Punchtype,Date,TotalTime,Job)
  Values ('1234','C','4/24/2017',4,'J1234'), ('1234','RW','4/24/2017',4,'J1234'),('4563','C','4/24/2017',2,'J1234'), ('4563','C','4/24/2017',5,'J1234')

  Update temp set exported = 1 where exists ( select null from temp group by employeeid,Date,Job having Min(punchtype) = MAX(punchtype))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CTE` and window functions:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            MIN(punchtype) 
            OVER(PARTITION BY employeeid, [Date], Job) Min_punchtype,
            MAX(punchtype) 
            OVER(PARTITION BY employeeid, [Date], Job) Max_punchtype
    FROM Temp
)
UPDATE CTE
SET exported = 1
WHERE Min_punchtype = Max_punchtype
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use this update:

```
Update temp set exported = 1 where temp.Employeeid = ( select temp.Employeeid from temp group by employeeid,Date,Job having Min(punchtype) = MAX(punchtype) );
```